# Can I do Find_Or_Create in model before save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, model

- So i'm looking to move a find_or_create function from my controller to my model. Bascially, if the location already exists then choose that, if not then create a new one.  From a bit of reading, I think a before save function should do it, but I'm not sure on the correct syntax and can't seem to find many examples anywhere.

*Location.rb*

```
before_save :get_locations

def get_locations
      Location.find_or_create_by(name: [:name])
end
```

Here's my controller; it was working fine when running the find_or_create here.

*Locations_controller.rb*

```
def create
   @location = Location.new(location_params) 

# == worked previously ==  #
# @location = Location.find_or_create_by(name: location_params[:name])
# == worked previously ==  #    

    respond_to do |format|
...
      end
    end
```

Help would be great!

Comment: It is not clear on what you are trying to achieve. WHy did you move this logic into a model - you shouldn't do this if those models are not related to each other. Also your `get_locations` method do absolutely nothing, except of wasting time for unneeded sql query to get records which are being discarded later. Please update your question with more details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: In model you have made endless loop, because `create` triggers `before_save` filter.

Comment: Are you possibly looking for the `before_action` callback for controllers?

Comment: Hi @BroiSatse - Aplogies, the models are related (one post has many locations). I'm looking to catch the location before save and check whether it exisits. If so, reference it, if not, create it.

Comment: @maringan  - not sure if before save is the correct callback. Open to suggestions. This just made most sense to me.

Comment: @JamesOsborn - Ok, just to be sure. You want to create a new model with given attributes and before save you want to check whether there already exists a model with this name in your database. If it exists you want to update existing record, if not create new one. Is it correct?

Comment: @BroiSatse Yep- that's exactly what i'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

First I'll try to guess, what is that you want to do there. Considering what you've given us, you are trying to prevent the creation of several locations with the same name and if a user tries to do that, find him the already created location instead of creating a new one.

If that's true, then there're couple things to mention:

1. You don't need any before_create methods there. All the model needs to have is a `validates_uniqueness_of :name` call so there would never be 2 locations with the same name.
2. You need to move that creation logic back into the controller. You can use the `find_or_initialize_by(name:location_params[:name])` call (in case you want to do something with the found record afterwards) or `find_or_create_by(name:location_params[:name])` (to create it right away).

Comment: Hi @Almaron. Will this not throw a validation error if I try to save a model with the same name? I still want the submit to succeed - but just to find the record which currently exists. i know I can do this in the controller - is it possible to do it in the model?

Comment: I think that kind of logic belongs in the controller. `find_or_create_by` should make the form submit succeed.